# loop to add a number to a variable

Tags: bash

I'm trying to figure out if this is possible? in Bash on Mac

```
var1="ABC"
var2="CDF"
....
var7

A="Monday CDF Day"
```

Have a loop 1-7 `var1 ... var10`

```
for ((i=0;i<10;i++))
if [[ $A == *"$var$i"]] # find the right pattern of var(x) as near match to (A)

 C=$var$i
   echo $C > whatsmyvar.txt
   exit
fi
...
```

So effectively (i) in the loop adds to the end of var to make var1, var2.., next in the loop, but var1 then 2...7 etc retains its variable data in tacked.

I could have loads of elif, but want to keep the code as slim as possible.

Many thanks for any help, and apologies if this sounds like an odd way of doing things?

Comment: Please define your understanding of "as near match to (A)". I am afraid here is no place for fuzzy logic.

Answer (score 1):

Issues and assumptions:

- the handful of syntax issues can be addressed by cutting-n-pasting the code (along with appropriate shebang) into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/)
- assuming the objective is to find a `varX` variable that is a substring of the `A` variable
- assuming OP's desired output is to store the `varX` value in the variable `C`
- while dynamic variable references are doable a more straightforward approach may be to use an array

One idea using an array to store the `varX` values:

```
unset C var

declare -a var

var[1]="ABC"
var[2]="CDF"
var[3]="XYZ"

A="Monday CDF Day"

for ((i=1;i<=3;i++))
do
    if [[ "${A}" =~ "${var[i]}" ]]
    then
        C="${var[i]}"
        break
    fi
done

echo "C = ${C}"
```

This generates:

```
C = CDF
```